# How to check next number and compare it to the previous one

Tags: java, arrays

I have got an array of numbers of size 14 which is filled with -1 where its blank, rest of numbers are as in following example [2,3,4,7,8, -1, -1...].

How would I compare the numbers so that they are 1 apart, and take first and last number from that comparison. So here I would compare |2-3|=1, |3-4|=1, |4-7|=3, I would take 2 as first number and 4 as last number and then compare the other half, so |7-8|=1 and then 7 is first number and 8 is last number.

```
            int diff = 0;
            int firstNum = 0;
            int lastNum = 0;
            for (int j=0; j < temp.length; j++){
                if (temp[j] != -1){

                    diff = Math.abs(temp[j] - temp[j+1]);

                    if (diff <= 1){
                        // first and last number
                        firstNum = temp[j];
                        lastNum = temp[j+1];
                    }
                    else {
                        firstNum = temp[j];
                        lastNum = temp[j+1];
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you want to do when the difference is greater than 1? How are you picking the first and last number? Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: When the difference is grater then 1 I want to print out first and last number, so it would print 2 4 and 7 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
int diff = 0;
int firstNum = temp[0];
int lastNum = temp[0];
for (int j=0; j < temp.length - 1; j++){
    if (temp[j] != -1){

        diff = Math.abs(temp[j] - temp[j+1]);

        if (diff <= 1){
            // last number
            lastNum = temp[j+1];
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("First number: " + firstNum + ", last number: " + lastNum);
            firstNum = temp[j+1];
            lastNum = temp[j+1];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Upon inspection, this seems to do the job, but you will get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException the last time you call `temp[j+1]`.  I think the `for` loop terminal should be `j < temp.length - 1`.

Comment: You're right. I didn't check that, just copied the OP loop.

Comment: Shouldn't it be -2? .length gives the number of elements. Since you are accessing them from 0 that means you can access till .length() -1 but now we are accessing the next element so we'll have to use .length() -2

Comment: @wandering-warrior There is `<`, not `<=` comparison. We have 14 elements, so length is 14, last index is 13, and `j < length - 1 = 13`, then last `j` is 12 and `j + 1` is 13.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..,

```
        int diff = 0;
        bool flag = false;
        int firstNum = 0;
        int lastNum = 0;
        for (int j=0; j < temp.length-1; j++){
            if (temp[j] != -1 && temp[j+1] != -1){
                diff = Math.abs(temp[j] - temp[j+1]);

                if (diff <= 1){
                    if(firstNum == 0)
                       firstNum = temp[j];
                    lastNum = temp[j+1];
                    flag = false;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(firstNum + ", " + lastNum);
                    firstNum = 0;
                    flag = true;
                }

            }
              if (!flag)
              System.out.println(firstNum + ", " + lastNum);
        }
```

If i didn't do the flag thing, it'd print it twice. There might be some other efficient way to do this.

Comment: It prints 2,4 but not 7,8

Comment: Check it now. @Jaskowaty